# Does a path exist going through each color only once?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, network-flow

I have a directed, colored graph (each node has a color), and I want to find if a path from node A to node B exists such that the path goes through each color at MOST once.

I think this problem can be formulated using network flow. Somehow a penalty can be placed on nodes of the same color that makes the flow 0 or infinity if a node is repeated.

Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be a slightly rephrased form of the [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), [seven bridges problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg), or [five rooms problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_room_puzzle).  The former is famous for having many complex algorithms to calculate it, and the latter are famous for, well, being mathematically proven as unsolvable.  This is an NP-complete problem.  It's very much non-trivial unless your plan is to brute force it, and that's going to be O(n!).

Comment: @BaconBits: We're not asking for the *shortest* path that satisfies the condition, just whether there is one.  The answers posted so far (simple search with backtracking) will give a very reasonable running time if such a path is fairly easy to find.  The worst case will still be on the order of O(n!) (i.e. when there is no path, or when one exists but maximal backtracking happened at every node.)

Answer (score 2):

This is NP-hard by reduction from special case of "path with forbidden pairs" problem where all forbidden pairs are required to be disjoint. Just assign some color to each forbidden pair. "Path with forbidden pairs" is a well-known NP-hard problem (and it remains NP-hard even in the case of disjoint pairs). In Garey and Johnson's book it has identifier "GT54".

But if number of non-unique colors (`k`) is a small constant, you could apply modified BFS algorithm with time complexity O(|E| * 2 <sup>2*k</sup>).

Here I explain this BFS algorithm (starting with simplified version):

Colors of all nodes visited by the path should be encoded into bitset, for example, if we have 3 available colors (red, green, blue) and a path that visited green node, this is encoded as `010`; after this path also visits red node, it is encoded as `011`. Path colors are stored in BFS queue along with last visited node.

Each node should store some "visited" flag for each color combination. Assuming example with three colors, each unvisited node would store 8 booleans with "false" value. After visiting this node with red/green path, its "visited" flags should be changed to following:

```
index.bool  index.dec  visited_flag
       000          0         false
       001          1         false
       010          2         false
       011          3          true
       100          4         false
       101          5         false
       110          6         false
       111          7         false
```

If algorithm encounters the same node while processing a path with same color combination, it should ignore it because of "true" visited flag.

Pseudocode for main loop of BFS algorithm may be rewritten as this:

```
 while Q is not empty:

     (u, c) = Q.dequeue()

     for each node n that is adjacent to u:
         if (c & n.color) == 0 && n.visited[c] == false:
             n.visited[c] = true
             Q.enqueue((n, c | n.color))
```

Algorithm terminates as usual: either destination is reached (path exists) or BFS queue becomes empty (path does not exist).

Worst case time complexity of this algorithm is O(|E| * 2 <sup>k</sup>). Still it is doing lots of redundant work. Since in BFS algorithm shorter (and less colorful) paths are considered earlier than longer paths, it is likely that some node is visited first with a red path, then by a green path, and then by a red/green path. And in this case processing this red/green path could not give any improvement. Which means we can speed up the algorithm by marking red/green as "visited" earlier, while processing green path. This optimization is not free: it requires to mark several flags while processing each path/node combination, and it increases worst case time complexity to O(|E| * 2 <sup>2*k</sup>). But all additional work is done locally, inside a node. Also if all 2<sup>k</sup> flags fit into a single CPU register, all this work could be done in parallel, with bitwise logical operations.

Comment: The NP-Hardness makes sense... Thanks! Could you explain the O(E*2^2k) algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Just do normal DFS, but also keep a list of colors and a boolean value with each. If you are about to visit a node with some color, and the corresponding boolean is false, set it to true and visit it; otherwise do not visit that node and keep recursing. If you terminate without getting to B then obviously there is no path.

EDIT: if some chosen path doesn't work, and the recursion backtracks, *reset* the booleans associated with the colors of the nodes you backtrack past.

Comment: Are you sure about this? What if I have a graph with red and blue nodes, and the first blue node I encounter is NOT on the desired path, but the second blue node is. In this case, the second blue will be discarded due to the first...?

Comment: @PK5144 ah yes, sorry. will edit with solution to caveat

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Just for clarification, the runtime of DFS is normally O(E). With the backtracking, won't the worst case be exponential, or can we guarantee better?

Comment: @PK5144 "backtracking" simply means "unrolling" the recursion - i.e. if a node's child paths don't lead to B correctly, the recursion returns to its previous node. At this point, unmark the boolean associated with this node's color. So the complexity is unchanged (assuming looking up the color is O(1), which may be done by pre-indexing / hashtables as George suggested)

Comment: An easier way to express this is to say "keep a **set** of the colors visited".  Set-membership is the boolean condition.  For dense sets, bitmaps are good.  For sparse sets, hash tables are good.  Both support constant-time test/add/remove operations.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wanted to do it using a search algorithm, you'd use most probably depth-first with backtracking, removing (or marking as already visited) each node you visit from the graph

would be keeping a hashtable for visited colors to quickly check each new color you find if known or not (or checking the visited path on the graph from A to C [=current] or from C to A [doesn't matter] if you can't use a separate structure but only attach properties on the graph).

For backtracking you could check the next outgoing link after you backtrack back to a node from an outgoing link that led to dead-end (couldn't reach B that is). This assumes links have some implicit ordering (that is can ask for the next link - and check if it is an outgoing one or ask for next till no more are available - when you have a node and some other outgoing link of it via which you came back while backtracking))

however, there should be better algorithms that do some (parallelizable) preprocessing of the graph and attach values on nodes and/or links that can help searches from a given color or from any color

Comment: btw, could also search in parallel from B to A to see if you reach a deadend from there faster than you reach one from A to B. In that case you know there is no solution (say you have B placed inside the smaller one of two nested "circles" of the same color and A is further away outside the 2nd circle)